# TFS warehouse refresh interval - where to change it

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to refresh TFS 2010 warehouse manually?

How can I change the interval of the warehouse refreshment?

Answer (score 2):

To change the refreshment interval for warehouse, you must be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group or have the server-level Administer warehouse permission set to Allow.

From Application tier machine, start Internet Explorer and go to

```
http://localhost:<8080 or other port you use>/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
```

You will see available web services there. You need to go to ChangeSetting option.

Enter in the SettingId: RunIntervalSeconds and in the newValue the number of seconds for the refreshment interval you need. Click on Invoke and you are all done.

For more information, you can check http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/11/25/Refresh-the-TFS-Warehouse-manually.aspx